# Retrieve nested element value with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to use lodash in order to retrieve a value from a nested array element in an Array of JSON.
I want to retrieve the planned value from a specific budget.

I.e. Informing **TI00104** should give me **$ 130,00**

I tried `_.filter(my_json, {budgetList: {budget: 'TI00104'}});`
but the return was an empty array.

```
var my_json = {  
    "department":"TI",
    "fiscal_year":"2019",
    "expense":"Vehicle Rent",
    "expense_description":"Credit Card payment",
    "user_cc":"2150",
    "accounting_account":"34101022",
    "budgetList":[  
        {  
            "budget":"TI00104",
            "planned":"$ 130,00"
        },
        {  
            "budget":"TI00105",
            "planned":"$ 140,00"
        }]
   };
```

Could you guys help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `_.find()` instead of `_.filter()`, and it `my_json.budgetList`, and use a flat object as the predicate. Use `_.get()` to get the `planned` value.

```js
var my_json = {"department":"TI","fiscal_year":"2019","expense":"Vehicle Rent","expense_description":"Credit Card payment","user_cc":"2150","accounting_account":"34101022","budgetList":[{"budget":"TI00104","planned":"$ 130,00"},{"budget":"TI00105","planned":"$ 140,00"}]};

var result = _.get(
  _.find(my_json.budgetList, {budget: 'TI00104'})
, 'planned');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var my_json = {"department":"TI","fiscal_year":"2019","expense":"Vehicle Rent","expense_description":"Credit Card payment","user_cc":"2150","accounting_account":"34101022","budgetList":[{"budget":"TI00104","planned":"$ 130,00"},{"budget":"TI00105","planned":"$ 140,00"}]};
   
let op = my_json.budgetList.find(({budget}) => budget ==="TI00104")

if(op){
  console.log(op.planned)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could skip lodash and use built-in `Array.prototype.filter()`.

```js
let myJson = {
  "department":"TI",
  "fiscal_year":"2019",
  "expense":"Vehicle Rent",
  "expense_description":"Credit Card payment",
  "user_cc":"2150",
  "accounting_account":"34101022",
  "budgetList":[  
    {  
      "budget":"TI00104",
      "planned":"$ 130,00"
    },
    {  
      "budget":"TI00105",
      "planned":"$ 140,00"
    }]
};
 
function getBudget(budgetName) {
  return myJson.budgetList.filter((b) => b.budget === budgetName)[0].planned;
}


console.log(`Budget: ${getBudget('TI00104')}`);
```